# How to pass value from protected method to a public method?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I created a global variable idprof and then set it to an id(you can find it in the protected void doinbackground) . And i want to put the value of it inside the namevaluepairs in the public String getCourseFromDB method, but it doesn't work. Can you help me, i'm sometimes confused in passing variables between methods (you can see my comments in my code)

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,String,Void>{
Context context; 
String command;

String idprof=""; // this is the global variable 

BackgroundWorker (Context ctx,String command){ 

    context = ctx;
    this.command = command;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        extras.putString("id", id.trim());

        idprof=id.trim(); //this is the value i want to get

        intent.putExtras(extras);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        }

}
return null;
}
public String getCourseFromDB() {
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs2;
        nameValuePairs2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",idprof)); // this is where i want to pass it


}
}
```

Comment: How about you figure out the **minimal** amount of code that will demonstrate your issue, and post that? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hmm i cant delete some of them because it might be important to you to see :( But i added //comments there to emphasize the issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). Please reduce your example to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add the *complete* stacktrace/Error message you get.

Comment: i updated it :) deleted unnecessary parts and i added //comments, the comments emphasizes my main issue

Comment: okay ill just delete one more time

Comment: it's short now? is that okay? sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Deleting lines arbitrarily to make your code shorter is not the way to create a [mcve]. Asking a question properly takes a reasonable amount of effort, not a quick fix.

Comment: It;s okay if all of you dont want to answer, i already know ;) I akready said i add comments there and all. but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried to guess your code. Please find bellow explanation

```
public class Main {
    String str = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m1 = new Main();
        m1.setTheValueHere();
        m1.getTheValueHere("called by m1");

        Main m2 = new Main();
        m2.getTheValueHere("called by m2");
    }

    protected void setTheValueHere(){
        str = "hello";
    }

    public void getTheValueHere(String objName) {
        System.out.println(objName +" --- "+str);
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
called by m1 --- hello
called by m2 --- null
```

Here the `String str` is an instance variable. For object `m1`, `hello` got printed since both set and get method is called by the same object `m1`. The value set by `m1` is not available for object `m2` since it is different object instance, hence for `m2` `null` is printed.

If you change `String str` to `static` variable as `static String str = null;` the output will be

```
called by m1 --- hello
called by m2 --- hello
```

because it is now class variable and hence shared to all the instances of that class.

Please check this explanation, you may get some idea about your problem.